# Could not find oauth1-0.4.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth

I have developing my application w/ no problems for a couple of months now. Today as I was trying to create a model using `rails g model ...` I get the following message in my terminal window:

`Could not find oauth1-0.4.1 in any of the sources`

How can I determine where this message is coming from so that I can continue my development. I don't recall adding any sort of gem that would require this.

https://img.skitch.com/20110525-93sat2axsrw9nneusew8e1kmu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running `sudo bundle install` or paste the complete exception. It seems that rails is having problem in loading the environment.

Comment: It's not an exception that gets throw in the app like in the browser window. It's just an output in the terminal that I get. I also got this when trying to run `rvmsudo bundle install`. See [screenshot](https://img.skitch.com/20110525-93sat2axsrw9nneusew8e1kmu.png).

Comment: Look in your Gemfile for the gem named oauth1 or similar. Remove the entry and try again. If it is not in the Gemfile try looking in Gemfile.lock . It may be a dependency of some other gem. Try removing that gem from your Gemfile and run bundle install again.